# Issue dsplaying GeoJSON file in OpenLayers 3.9.0

Tags: geojson, openlayers

I'm trying to get vector feature from geojson file displayed in openlayers 3.9.0.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": {"type": "name","properties": {"name": "EPSG:3857"}},
"features": [{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [0, 0]}}]}
```

Does anyone see why this code does not do it?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
          }),
          new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
              url: 'data.json',
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that reading the geojson from an internally defined object works fine:

```
  var geojsonObject = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {"type": "name","properties": {"name": "EPSG:3857"}},
    "features": [
      {"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [0, 0]}}
    ]
  }
  ...
  new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source arguments need some corrections. You use the object key "source" twice. Replace the 2nd with "format":

```
source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'data.json',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
```

Comment: I have corrected it but it still won't work.

Comment: There can be many reasons. Do you get an error message? 
(Press F12 for opening the developer tools in Fire Fox or Chrome)

Comment: Here is the error message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/gsdata/www/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: This error happens when you want to access files from another domain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Do you use an apache server? you have to access it by using "localhost/index.html". Not recommended would be to switch of the restriction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: I was lanching my map file by just clicking on it. I have geoserver instaled and have just tried accessing the file by `http:/<host:port>/geoserver/www/` link and it works!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad to help :-)